# How do I pull data from a row in another sheet based on value in the first sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Probably a very simple questions but can't find a simple answer.

First sheet "Plan" in C3 I have an integer value. In that C3 I want to indicate a row number from which to pull from in another sheet.

I have another sheet "Stock Market" which from which I want to pull information from, from Column A.

Basically something like this.
='Stock Market'!A[a value from C3]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the non volatile INDEX():

```
=INDEX('Stock Market'!$A:$A,C3)
```